Model that gets burnt. Surgeon husband repairs fail
I`m trying to find a film l watched in the 70's. I believe it's British..
Memory is quite fragmented as I was about 8/9 years old..
I remember it was in colour.
It was about a fashion model that gets burnt in an accident with a camera light or could be lighting used in a photo shoot she was doing.
She ended up badly disfigured on one side of her face. I believe her husband was a plastic surgeon.
He tries to make her beautiful again, by murdering girls and harvesting/transplanting their facial skin onto hers. The surgery is never successful, as the skin`s never accepted and just rots, after a certain amount of time.
I can't remember the ending..

Thanks Paulie.. Mystery solved Corruption 1968.. Years of trying to remember name, and it took one evening here to solve it.. What a brilliant site! :D
